# Is this empty space actually margin-right which is not recognized by dev tools?

Tags: html, css

According to CSS spec rule(content-box), the width of the containing block is equal to sum of 7 horizontal properties:

margin-left + border-width-left + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-width-right+ margin-right.

In the example below if the above rule is to be true the 300px to the right must be treated as margin-right but the chrome dev tools shows margin-right as 0:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: content-box;  
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: SeaGreen;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: LightGreen;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  what is the 300px space to the right of this p called?<br>
  It looks like margin-right but the dev tools computed value
  for margin-right is 0.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66213429/8620333

Comment: There is no margin. Parent element has `width: 500px`, `p` just `width: 200px`.

Comment: @pavel margin-right of p

Comment: @ChrisOdney: there is no margin.

Comment: Your equation (`totalElementWidth = width + margins + borders + paddings`) is right, but the sum doesn't need to be 100% of parent element. Real `p` width is 200px (200px + 6x0)) the rest of parent element is empty space irrelavant to paragraph.

Comment: @pavel if there is no margin the example is not adhering to the CSS specification then.

Comment: @TemaniAfif So the 'used value' of margin-right is 300px while the computed value is 0px and so the chrome dev tools is correct?

Comment: @ChrisOdney: where is in the CSS spec written, that `margin-right` is `100% parent width - real element width`? It's just your misunderstanding how CSS works.

Comment: @pavel  here is the equation: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth the sum need to be equal to containing block width

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Yes, so you can read whole block... There are 5 `if`s, one of them is `if width != auto`...

Comment: @Pavel That's correct. So in this case with the width not being auto, now what would you call that space to the right of the <p>, empty space which hasn't been named in the CSS spec?

Comment: @Pavel I read what you wrote and hence the question.

Comment: @pavel what you said it not completely true, there is no "irrelevant space", that space is margin like defined in the spec

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think it is safe to consider it as margin, as there is no other space defined in the spec? If that's the case I am surprised why chrome dev tools does not recognize it as margin.

Comment: @ChrisOdney I don't believe any of the answers posted are correct. The error is in the understanding of the spec though. There is no `margin-right`, whether computed or not. The child element simply has a smaller width value than its parent. The space between the two is the mathematical difference, not a margin. This can be seen by adding `margin-right: 0 !important;` to then element itself. If the space were in any way a margin that the browser simply wasn't respecting, the space would then disappear, but it does not, because it is not margin-related at all.

Comment: The space to the right is not the sum of those seven properties. The total width (the `outerWidth` property in JavaScript) of the element is the sum of those seven properties, and it is. That value is 200px, which is the value of the width CSS property of the child element itself. That has no bearing whatsoever on the space to its right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Temani's answer says, the essential difference is between the computed value of the right margin, which is 0px and the used value, which is 300px in your example.

What is confusing is what are the "computed" values depicted in the dev tools.

The Computed value of a property has a very particular meaning. When a child element *inherits* the value of a property, that Computed value becomes the child's Specified value of that same property. So, if the computed value for width of a block element is, say, 50% of its container, and its block child has `width:inherit` then that child will be 50% of 50% (= 25%) of the outer container, rather than inheriting the pixel value of the parent.

```css
html {
  background-color:white;
}
* { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom:10px; margin:0; }
body {
  width: 300px;
  background-color:lightyellow;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
p {
  width:inherit;
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

However, there is a CSSOM method `window.getComputedStyle()`. For backward compatibility reasons sometimes this needs to return the pixel value rather than the true Computed value.

For that reason, CSSOM defines another value, called the [Resolved value](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#resolved-values). `getComputedStyle()` then, despite its name returns the Resolved values of the properties, not their Computed values.

Now, the CSSOM spec says that for width, margin and some other properties, the Resolved value is the Used value, where for most other properties, it's the Computed value. This allows `getComputedStyle()` to maintain its backward compatibility, while implementing the inheritable computed values correctly.

However, it turns out that browsers don't implement this faithfully. If they did, then in your example, the Resolved value of margin-right would take into account the adjustment to satisfy the equality and return 300px. In fact, what is actually returned is the Computed value converted to pixels. i.e. The value *before* the adjustment for the equality.

This discrepancy is documented in a currently open CSSOM issue: [Used value of margin properties #2328](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2328).

The values shown in the Computed tab of dev tools match the values returned by `getComputedStyle()`. Not always the computed value, not always the used value, and for margins, and not even the resolved value as it is currently defined.

Answer (score 3):

The browser always show **computed values** like you can see below:

[image]

[The specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) talk about **used values**

> The following constraints must hold among the **used values** of the other properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

So the computed value is `0` but the used value is `300px`

Another example:

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: content-box;  
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: SeaGreen;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: LightGreen;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>what is the 300px space to the right of this p called?<br>
    It looks like margin-right but the dev tools computed value for margin-right is 0. </p>
</div>
```

The computed value is `10px` but still the used value is like in your first example

> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" **and one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value**. If the 'direction' property of the containing block has the value 'ltr', the **specified value of 'margin-right' is ignored and the value is calculated so as to make the equality**

Related question: [why is right margin of overconstrained element not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66210839/8620333)

Comment: Exactly what I understood from the comments! Just another clarification please: when the width is in % the computed value still remains in % (according to specs? ) and it is only the used value which is in absolute length but the dev tools clearly shows this under it's computed section.

Comment: @ChrisOdney you are right, it's probably a different behavior with *width* but technically the percentage is a computed value and the pixel should be the used one. Will try to see if I find a logical explanation to this

Comment: @Alohci I made the answer a wiki one so feel free to correct it :) (I cannot delete it since it's accepted now)

Comment: @Alohci well, it's too much to digest at once :) maybe you can compile your comments into an answer. It might be useful in case questions like that will arise. It would be a good dupe target as I doubt we have such details in another answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will accept Alohci's answer but please do not delete this one, let it stay. Thanks. Unless it's negating your rep score!